# Co-inductive hypothesis for transitivity of stream bisimulation

Tags: coq

Catalin Hritcu [published](https://hritcu.wordpress.com/2012/12/23/learning-teaching-coinduction-with-coq/) some [notes on coinduction in Coq](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/670Fall12/HW6.v), including a discussion of coinduction principles in the style of [Giménez and Castéran](http://www.labri.fr/perso/casteran/RecTutorial.pdf). One of the exercises is to show that stream bisimulation is transitive using the following coinduction principle:

```
stream_eq_coind
     : forall (A : Type) (R : stream A -> stream A -> Prop),
       (forall s1 s2 : stream A, R s1 s2 -> head s1 = head s2) ->
       (forall s1 s2 : stream A, R s1 s2 -> R (tail s1) (tail s2)) ->
       forall s1 s2 : stream A, R s1 s2 -> stream_eq s1 s2
```

The "hard part", if any, is finding a coinduction hypothesis. Here is mine:

```
Definition stream_eq_trans_principle {A : Type} (t1 t3 : stream A) := 
  exists t2, stream_eq t1 t2 /\ stream_eq t2 t3.
```

The proof follows naturally.

My question: is this the "canonical" induction hypothesis for this problem, or is there a different one which is considered more elegant?

Here is some stand-alone code for experimenting with.

```
Require Import Relations RelationClasses.

Set Implicit Arguments.

CoInductive stream (A : Type) : Type :=
  | scons : A -> stream A -> stream A.

CoInductive stream_eq (A : Type) {eqA : relation A} `{EQ : Equivalence A eqA} : stream A -> stream A -> Prop :=
| eqstep : forall h1 h2 t1 t2, eqA h1 h2 -> stream_eq t1 t2 -> stream_eq (scons h1 t1) (scons h2 t2).

Section stream_eq_coind.
  Variable A : Type.
  Variable eqA : relation A.
  Context `{EQ : Equivalence A eqA}.
  Variable R : relation (stream A).

  Hypothesis H1 : forall h1 h2 t1 t2,
    R (scons h1 t1) (scons h2 t2) -> eqA h1 h2.
  Hypothesis H2 : forall h1 h2 t1 t2,
    R (scons h1 t1) (scons h2 t2) -> R t1 t2.

  Theorem stream_eq_coind : forall s1 s2 : stream A,
    R s1 s2 -> stream_eq s1 s2.
  Proof. 
    cofix. intros s1 s2 H0.
    destruct s1, s2.

    specialize (H1 H0). simpl in H1. subst.
    specialize (H2 H0). simpl in H2.
    specialize (stream_eq_coind _ _ H2) as H3. clear stream_eq_coind.
    apply (eqstep a a0 H1 H3).
  Qed.

End stream_eq_coind.

Check stream_eq_coind.

Lemma stream_eq_refl : forall {A : Type} (s : stream A),
  stream_eq s s.
Proof.
  intros.
  apply stream_eq_coind with (R := fun s1 s2 => s1 = s2).
  - intros. inversion H. reflexivity.
  - intros. inversion H. reflexivity.
  - reflexivity.
Qed.

Lemma stream_eq_sym : forall {A : Type} (s1 s2 : stream A),
  stream_eq s1 s2 -> stream_eq s2 s1.
Proof.
  intros.
  apply stream_eq_coind with (R := fun s1 s2 => stream_eq s2 s1).
  - intros. inversion H0. subst. reflexivity.
  - intros. inversion H0. apply H6.
  - assumption.
Qed.

Definition stream_eq_trans_principle {A : Type} (t1 t3 : stream A) := exists t2, stream_eq t1 t2 /\ stream_eq t2 t3.

Lemma stream_eq_trans : forall {A : Type} (s1 s2 s3 : stream A),
  stream_eq s1 s2 -> stream_eq s2 s3 -> stream_eq s1 s3.
Proof.
  intros A s1 s2 s3 Eq1 Eq2.
  apply stream_eq_coind with (R := stream_eq_trans_principle).
  - intros h1 h3 t1 t3 [t2 [Eq1' Eq2']].
    inversion Eq1'. subst.
    inversion Eq2'. subst.
    reflexivity.
  - intros h1 h3 t1 t3 [t2 [Eq1' Eq2']].
    inversion Eq1'. subst.
    inversion Eq2'. subst.
    exists t4. repeat split; assumption.
  - unfold stream_eq_trans_principle. eauto.
Qed.
```

Comment: Please provide a self-contained file. It'll make it easier for people to experiment when trying to answer your question.

Comment: I've added some code.